# How to get numeric key of new pushed item in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

```
$arr[] = $new_item;
```

Is it possible to get the newly pushed item programmatically?

Note that it's not necessary `count($arr)-1`:

```
$arr[1]=2;
$arr[] = $new_item;
```

In the above case,it's `2`

Comment: Edit: Ignore me, I misread the question. Pushed which interactive element? Button, radio button, checkboxes or ...?

Comment: Bryan and Haim's answers both work... however more often than not when someone asks a question like this they don't really care about the last key of the array, they really want the last element in the array.  If that's the case, just use the `end()` function by itself and don't worry about it's key.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`max(array_keys($array))` should do the trick

Answer (score 13):

`end()` do the job , to return the value ,

if its help to you ,

you can use `key()` after to petch the key.

after i wrote the answer , i see function in this link :

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.end.php

```
function endKey($array){
 end($array);
 return key($array);
}
```

Comment: I don't think that will work. From the PHP Docs:
"Every array has an internal pointer to its 'current' element, which is initialized to the first element inserted into the array." It's possible `end()` might do the job

Answer (score 2):

The safest way of doing it is:

```
$newKey = array_push($array, $newItem) - 1;
```

Comment: This seems like it will work. But it doesn't "feel" right. Am I missing something here?

Comment: It's the cleanest I've come up with so far.

Comment: I know that's old, but array_push doesn't return the key. It returns the length of the array. Adding arbitrary keys might introduce bugs. It only works if the keys are sequential, starting from zero.

Comment: @PedroAmaralCouto Yes, this is a simple solution for indexed arrays. In php, arrays with arbitrary keys are considered associative arrays and require a different treatment.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
max(array_keys($array,$new_item))
```

`array_keys($array,$new_item)` will return all the keys associated with value `$new_item`, as an array.

Of all these keys we are interested in the one that got added last and will have the `max` value.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a variable to keep track of the number of items in an array:

```
$i = 0;
$foo = array();
$foo[++$i] = "hello";
$foo[++$i] = "world";

echo "Elements in array: $i" . PHP_EOL;
echo var_dump($foo);
```

Comment: This will overwrite existing keys, and if there are none offers no benefit over just using `$foo[]`, apart from making a one-based array (which may or may not be a benefit).

Answer (score 0):

if it's newly created, you should probably keep a reference to the element. :)

You could use `array_reverse`, like this:

```
$arr[] = $new_item;
...
$temp = array_reverse($arr);
$new_item = $temp[0];
```

Or you could do this:

```
$arr[] = $new_item;
...
$new_item = array_pop($arr);
$arr[] = $new_item;
```

If you are using the array as a stack, which it seems like you are, you should avoid mixing in associative keys. This includes setting `$arr[$n]` where `$n > count($arr)`. Stick to using `array_*` functions for manipulation, and if you must use indexes only do so if `0 < $n < count($arr)`. That way, indexes should stay ordered and sequential, and then you can rely on `$arr[count($arr)-1]` to be correct (if it's not, you have a logic error).