# How to get last key in array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is similar to this question,only PHP->javascript

[How to get numeric key of new pushed item in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197933/how-to-get-numeric-key-of-new-pushed-item-in-php)

Answer (score 20):

```
var foo = myarray[myarray.length - 1];
```

The preferred term is element, rather than key.

EDIT: Or do you mean the last index?  That is `myarray.length - 1`.  Keep in mind, JavaScript arrays can only be indexed numerically (though arrays are also objects, which causes some confusion).

Comment: @user198729 Arrays in JavaScript work differently than PHP. PHP implements them as sparse arrays which is why the index of the first/last element aren't always 0/len-1. In JavaScript all arrays are dense arrays, zero-base, fully populated (maybe undefined) index elements from 0 to .length-1.

Answer (score 6):

If it's a **flat array**, this would do:

```
return array.length - 1;
```

However, if you have an **associative array**, you'd have to know the key and loop through it. Please note though that JavaScript knows no such thing as an "associative array", as most elements in JavaScript are objects.

**Disclaimer:** Usage of associative arrays in JavaScript is [generally not a good practice](http://andrewdupont.net/2006/05/18/javascript-associative-arrays-considered-harmful/) and can lead to problems.

```
var x = new Array();
x['key'] = "value";
for (i in x)
{
    if (i == 'key')
    {
        alert ("we got "+i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why use an `Array`? You're not using the arrayness of it (i.e. the magic `length` property) so you might as well use an `Object`. Also, the JavaScript spec makes no guarantee about the order of the keys when using a `for...in` loop, so there's no such thing as the "last key"

Comment: In the first example, I used the length property. Since this property is not available on associative arrays, I added the second example, which cleary demonstrates a use case of a "simulated last key". Since the OP would know the name of the last key, it would be possible to get the actual element with the above method.

Comment: Re. the length property, I was referring to the second example, not the first.

Comment: Ah, I understand. OP specifically asked how to get a key in an `Array`, so that's why (even though it is technically still an `Object`). There are probably more refined ways to do this.

Answer (score 4):

I assume your array is a "key associated array" with string keys in  number format.
You will need to do it in 3 steps:

1. Get all array keys.
2. Convert array keys to an integer.
3. Get max or length or any other keys property.

```js
stringKeys = Object.keys(keyValueArray); // Get keys of array 
integerKeys = stringKeys.map(Number); // Convert to integer
mx = Math.max.apply(integerKeys); // Get max
len = stringKeys.length; // Get length
```

Hope I helped

Comment: then to answer the original question of what is the last key in the associative array I had to do : stringKeys[len-1] or if you want an integer integerKeys[len-1].

Answer (score 2):

The last key of an array is always `arr.length-1` as arrays always start with key `0`:

```
var arr = new Array(3);  // arr === [], arr.length === 3
arr.push(0);             // arr === [undefined, undefined, undefined, 0], arr.length === 4
arr[arr.length-1]        // returns 0

var arr = [];            // arr === [], arr.length === 0
arr[3] = 0;              // arr === [undefined, undefined, undefined, 0], arr.length === 4
arr[arr.length-1]        // returns 0
```

Answer (score 2):

If your array is an associative array([Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Basics)), I think the best way to do this is by using `Object.keys()`.

[From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys);

> The Object.keys() method returns an array of a given object's own property names, in the same order as we get with a normal loop.

First get the keys of the array in an numeric array.
Then get the last key, and use it in the Object.

```
var keys = Object.keys(my_array);
var last = keys[keys.length - 1];
console.log(my_array[last]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Math.max(...[...myArray.keys()]);
```

Here `myArray` is the name of an array.

This is a solution based on your referred question. Assuming the array is a single dimensional array or all the array keys are numeric.

Reads: 
[Math.max](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max), [Array.prototype.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/keys), [Iterators and generators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators)